# Recover IP register after ilegal memory read or jump

Tags: c, assembly, x86, operating-system, kernel

How can *Instruction Pointer* register recover from a bad read or bad jump?
Kernel makes the call to an `init` code that will call the `main()` program. If the `main()` program makes a stack overflow or whatever and `RIP/EIP/IP` fills with junk, how can the OS recover the CPU register?

CPU has only one *instruction pointer* right? So recovering from a overflow seems impossible to my point of view.

Comment: Single CPU different contexts.

Comment: If the CPU executes an instruction that generates and out-of-bounds or illegal read/write, then the memory management hardware will generate an interrupt and control will be transferred to the appropriate pre-configured handler irrespective of the address/es of the erroneous operation or IP contents at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you trash the IP in the usermode, eventually a hardware fault occurs, be it a page fault, illegal opcode or something like that. Then the processor switches to supervisor/kernel mode and starts running a fault handler by setting the instruction pointer to a well-defined value.

The kernel code will then inspect the address at which the exception happened and/or the type of the exception. Upon finding that it was because of any of these usually the kernel will then terminate the malfunctioning user-mode process.

Comment: understood. But how this can be achieved? I mean, I'm searching for a real code that can save process state, find the next process to restore and pass IP to that process and etc...
Does this have to scheduling algorithms? Like round-robin and FIFO?

Comment: Linux 0.01 had multitask? :o didn't know. thank you.

Comment: @int3 actually it does *not* recover from those faults in version 0.01, it just halts ;)

Comment: I'm reading include/linux/sched.h and what I'm understanding from this is that the kernel has a page with process ID, and a struct for all registers and segments. when a task is created it saves it in a, I'm guessing, a linked list with the structs of their last state right? Something like that.

Comment: @int3 yes that'd be correct. Nowadays a pointer to that struct would exist at the "bottom" of the kernel stack, so you could access it by aligning your stack pointer to the limit of your stack, and from there access the task structure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if the IP gets trashed and that causes a fault, only the bad value is known. It's unclear what you mean by "recovering from overflow". Of course the fault handler of the OS has a well defined address and the cpu goes there so IP will be well defined from then on. The OS may decide to terminate the process or if the program has installed a signal/exception handler the OS will make sure that is called. This handler can then load IP with an appropriate value.

Comment: hmm. so, after some research with appropriate keywords, I found "context switching" via software vs hardware.
Can I write asm code that switches from 2 functions hard coded, with no libs, just to learn how this works internally?

Answer (score 1):

If the IP gets loaded with an address from which it cannot execute, it triggers an **EXCEPTION**. A CPU usually recognizes a number of different types of exceptions and they are identified by a different number.

When the exception occurs, it causes the CPU to switch to kernel mode. That in turn causes the CPU to load the IP with the address of a handler defined to handle the specific type of exception and to load a kernel mode stack.

There are two types of exceptions: **faults** and **traps**. After a fault, the original instruction in the IP can be restarted. A trap is a fatal error. What happens at this point depends upon the type of exception.

If its a page fault, the handler will try to load the page into memory.

For most other exceptions, the handler will try to find a user mode handler for the specific type of exception. See the **signal** function in eunuchs.